# How to recover back linux OS after running HALT command

Tags: linux

I ran halt command on my Linux Terminal . Could you please let me  know how to access Linux terminal again in CENTOS Virtual Machine ?

Comment: Me? If my answer was helpful, do remember to upvote it (but you may need 15 reputation first), and if it's the best answer then [accept it](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) (with the check-mark next to it). StackExchange is a little different & [specifically says](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) they don't like comments only saying thanks (even though it's polite, it would clutter up the site with thanks messages everywhere, so upvoting / accepting is a better "thanks" here). Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your system's already been halted or powered off, then just reboot it.

Comment: If system is halted it isn't powered off.  You would need to power off and on the VM as it will not respond to reboot.  See this answer for difference between halt & poweroff : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195898/what-is-the-difference-between-these-commands-for-bringing-down-a-linux-server/196014#196014

Comment: That sounds right, I meant a generic "reboot" as in "turn it off & back on", the VM is an extra layer of "confusion" but depending on the specific software & it's version it might even have a [reset in it's menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXRwS.png) that may even do the trick, or "close" might have a popup asking about powering off or doing something else.